# I'm having trouble having my header transition to work on IOS

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

## Situation

I have the header on my site to be transparent if the sites is scrolled all the way up. Else be white

I need to change 3 elements in every transitions: Logo, link's colours and the background.

## The Issue

[Desktop Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dw3yVDW7b_U)

[IOS Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wgZGZ_szGw)

(I only have iPhones and iPads so I can't test on android)

Everything works fine on my desktop but when I use the site on an IOS device the following happens:

1. The website opens up with a scroll value of 0.
2. When I scroll down, 3 of 3 changes correctly.
3. When I scroll back to the top however, the background stays opaque.
   (Only 2 of 3 elements changes. (logo and the links).)

I found that if I scroll back to the top very slowly it works 1/3 times.

## What I've tried

Using rbga as the background value instead of "transparent"

## Here are my HTML tags:

#### Logo

```html
 <a class="navbar-brand mr-5"><img id="navbar-logo" src="../src/lib/images/logo-white.png" alt="MSC"></a>
```

#### Links

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="./index.html">Accueil</a>
       </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./services.html">Services</a>
       </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./equipe.html">Equipe</a>
       </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### Navbar

```
<nav id="home" class="container navbar-main navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
```

## CSS

```css
.navbar{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    transition: background 0.3s;
}
```

## JS

```js
let scrollValue = 0; //Scroll value
const navbar = document.getElementById("home"); //navbar
const navbarLogo = document.getElementById("navbar-logo"); //logo



window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
    //Changes 'scrollValue' for the current scrollY
    scrollValue = scrollY;
})

setInterval(event => {
    console.log(scrollValue)
    if (scrollValue < 10) {
        navbarTransition("light-trans");
    } else {
        navbarTransition("light");
    }
}, 250)` //Checks the scroll value every 250ms.


function navbarTransition(theme) {
    switch (theme) {
        case "light":
            navbarLogo.src = "../src/lib/images/logo.png";
            navbar.style.background = "#fff";
            navbar.classList.remove("navbar-dark");
            navbar.classList.add("navbar-light");
            break;
        case "light-trans":
            navbarLogo.src = "../src/lib/images/logo-white.png";
            navbar.style.background = "transparent";
            navbar.classList.remove("navbar-light");
            navbar.classList.add("navbar-dark");
            break;
    }
}
```

## +

If you have a better way of handling this please share, I'm just starting out.

Comment: Please rewrite the title to describe your point.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a snippet and did some changes. It should work.

```js
let scrollValue = 0; //Scroll value
const navbar = document.getElementById("home"); //navbar
const navbarLogo = document.getElementById("navbar-logo"); //logo



window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
  //Changes 'scrollValue' for the current scrollY
  scrollValue = scrollY;
})

setInterval(event => {
  if (scrollValue < 10) {
    navbarTransition("light-trans");
  } else {
    navbarTransition("light");
  }
}, 250)
//Checks the scroll value every 250ms.


function navbarTransition(theme) {
  switch (theme) {
    case "light":
      navbarLogo.src = "http://placehold.it/300x50.jpg";
      navbar.style.background = "#000";
      navbar.classList.remove("navbar-dark");
      navbar.classList.add("navbar-light");
      break;
    case "light-trans":
      navbarLogo.src = "http://placehold.it/30x50.jpg";
      navbar.style.background = "transparent";
      navbar.classList.remove("navbar-light");
      navbar.classList.add("navbar-dark");
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.navbar-light {
  background: red;
}

body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<nav id="home" class="container navbar-main navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">

  <a class="navbar-brand mr-5"><img id="navbar-logo" src="http://placehold.it/300x50.jpg" alt="MSC"></a>

  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="./index.html">Accueil</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./services.html">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./equipe.html">Equipe</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried your code but I still get the same results on IOS. I've noticed that if I use another color like red or blue instead of transparent, it works 100% of the time. I've added 2 videos on my post showing the problem.